# How to block horizontal scroll before that i arrive at the div

Tags: javascript, html, css, horizontal-scrolling

I created an horizontal scroll between two vertical scrolls. The problem is that while i scroll the first part vertically also the next divs start scroll horizontally. I need to stop the horizontal scroll until i'm arivved at the point of interest. Im testing on this exercise: http://effevisual.altervista.org

Thank you for the help.

```
<main style="overflow: scroll hidden">
  <div class="wrapper" >
    <div><img src="link"></div>
     <div><img src="link2"></div>
     <div><img src="link3"></div>
  </div>
</main>
```

```
main {
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 70vh;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-start;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    width: auto;
}

.wrapper > div {
    pointer-events: none;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```
<script>
var item = document.getElementsByTagName('MAIN')[0];

window.addEventListener('wheel', function(e) {

  if (e.deltaY > 0) item.scrollLeft += 100;
  else item.scrollLeft -= 100;
});
</script>
```